# Flow of initializing objects in XAML?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm not sure but from my hours of debugging, this should be the best description of my problem I can give.
I'm creating a WinRT app, there are two pages- Main Page and Details Page. Inside Main Page constructor, I have initialized a listbox. On click of any of the element of listbox, user is taken to the Details page.
I'm just learning all this and design may not be best but here is what I did. 
I took a static variable in MainPage.cs, and set it to point to the element which is clicked by the user. Now in the constructor of the Details page, I used this static variable to set the datacontext of Details Page itself.

What flow I'm expecting is:-

MainPage is created first. Listbox is setup.

User will click on any of the element of listbox. Itemclick event handler runs. It will set the static variable (of Mainpage.cs) to hold the infomation which item is clicked and navigate user to the Details page.

In Details page constructor, I have set the datacontext to point to some information based on the value of static variable mentioned in the previous step.

It works for most of the times, but once in like every 5 times, The Details page constructor throws an exception stating the static variable is not initialized yet. Why is Details  page's constructor running when I'm starting the app? and why only sometimes? Do I need to set DataContext of Details Page in some other method instead of constructor?

The code is somewhat complex and too much in terms of domain of the problem so I'm avoiding posting it. But if I'm failing to explain the problem please tell, I'll post it keeping it as related as I can.

CODE:-
This is the method called when an item in listbox is clicked--will take user to the Details page.

```
private void overviewlistbox_Tapped_1(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MatchOverview selectedmatch = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as MatchOverview;
    matchFullDetails = new ObservableCollection<Match>();

    foreach (Match m in UpdateController.matchList)
    {
        if (m.matchDescription == selectedmatch.matchDesc)
        {
            matchFullDetails.Add(m);
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!(matchFullDetails.Count == 0))
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Details)); 
}
```

This is the constructor for Main Page:-

```
public static ObservableCollection<Match> matchFullDetails;

public MainPage()
{
    matchFullDetails = new ObservableCollection<Match>();
    this.InitializeComponent();
    UpdateController update = new UpdateController();  // Creating new object will update the overview_list of UpdateController(static list).
    overviewlistbox.ItemsSource = UpdateController.overview_list; 
}
```

And this is the code for constructor of details page, where the exception occurs:-

```
public static ObservableCollection<Match> matchdetails = new ObservableCollection<Match>();
DispatcherTimer dtm_detailspage = null;

public Details()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    matchdetails = MainPage.matchFullDetails;       // matchdetails.Last<>() is take because we only need item which is added latest to the collection.
    if (matchdetails.Last<Match>().type == "TEST")  // Exception is thrown here--Initialization 
                                                    // error. When I check MainPage.matchFullDetails,
                                                    // no data is shown which means its not yet
                                                    // initialized. Also the exception is thrown either at 
                                                    // the start of the app, or when details page is visited. That too once in 4-5 times, not always.
    {
        matchdetails.Add(matchdetails.First<Match>() as TestMatch);
    }

    if (matchdetails.Last<Match>().type == "ODI")
    {
        matchdetails.Add(matchdetails.Last<Match>() as ODIMatch);
    }

    if (matchdetails.Last<Match>().type == "T20")
    {
        matchdetails.Add(matchdetails.Last<Match>() as T20Match);
    }                         
}
```

Exception Screenshot:-
[image: The exception thrown at run-time]

Call Stack data on bug encounter:-

[Cricket Expert.exe!Cricket_Expert.Details.Details() Line 33 + 0x5 bytes

[External Code]

Cricket Expert.exe!Cricket_Expert.Common.SuspensionManager.RestoreFrameNavigationState(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame frame) Line 236 + 0x5 bytes

Cricket Expert.exe!Cricket_Expert.Common.SuspensionManager.RestoreAsyn() Line 124 0x8 bytes

Cricket Expert.exe!Cricket_Expert.App.OnLaunched(Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.LaunchActivatedEventArgs args) Line 74 + 0x5 bytes

[External Code]

**MAJOR UPDATE: 
I finally found the flaw. If the Details page is still active, and the app is restarted, the problem occurs.
Is there a solution to this problem??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass information on what needs to be displayed on the Details page through the Navigate call and set the DataContext in OnNavigatedTo override to avoid using static variables. Pages don't get created unless you do it specifically e.g. by navigating to one. They might not be recreated if a page has NavigationCacheMode changed from the default (Disabled) so instances of the page can be reused during navigation calls. Ultimately it's hard to say what's wrong but it seems like something in your code and we couldn't help you if you don't share a sample that reproduces the problem.

*EDIT

One way to debug `Details` being created before `MainPage` would be to add this code at the beginning of the `Details` constructor:

```
if (MainPage.matchFullDetails == null)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
}
```

Then look at the `Call Stack` panel in Visual Studio to see how it gets constructed.

One way to see if `matchFullDetails` is ever set to null is to search for its assignment (put a cursor on `matchFullDetails` in Visual Studio code editor and hit Shift+F12).

Another way would be to make matchFullDetails into a property and test it like this:

```
private static ObservableCollection<Match> _matchFullDetails;
public static ObservableCollection<Match> matchFullDetails
{
    get
    {
        return _matchFullDetails;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }

        _matchFullDetails = value;
    }
}
```

*EDIT 2

You can initialize your static property in a static constructor like this:

```
public static ObservableCollection<Match> matchFullDetails;

static MainPage()
{
    matchFullDetails = new ObservableCollection<Match>();
}

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    UpdateController update = new UpdateController();  // Creating new object will update the overview_list of UpdateController(static list).
    overviewlistbox.ItemsSource = UpdateController.overview_list; 
}
```

- this will prevent the null reference exception but won't fix your problem overall. When your app gets suspended and resumed - you have to restore the full state and it seems like your matchFullDetails collection would need to be serialized and saved to disk when your app gets suspended. Alternatively you might simply ignore the suspension manager call in App.xaml.cs and always start on home page, though that's not a very good experience and I am not sure if it satisfies app certification.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe NavigationCacheMode is the problem. Does it affect when I restart the app from my visual studio? I mean does visual studio/RunTime tries to cache the details page?? I'll post the code shortly. Will try to keep it as related as possible.

Comment: I'm wondering if saying Last<Match>() might fail if matchdetails only contains nulls. Also if your app gets suspended, terminated and you go back to it and navigate to your Details page your MainPage class might have never been initialized. Do you have the actual exception details including any inner exceptions?

Comment: Caught the exception. Null Reference Exception was unhandled by user code. If app gets suspended/terminated, the app automatically goes to MainPage.

Comment: Is it matchdetails that is null or is it matchdetails.Last<Match>()?

Comment: matchdetails is null. I'm really stuck at this one. Don't really know why it occurs only once in a while? If a bug occurs everytime atleast I can try different things to see if it has been killed. But this one is really frustrating. Every different thing I try, thinks "OK bug maybe gone now", it comes up again.huhhhh :-(

Comment: Is there any chance you are setting it to null anywhere? There seem to be only two possible reasons why this happens - either you are setting it to null somewhere or for some reason you navigate or otherwise construct `Details` before you do `MainPage`. Your `App.xaml.cs` should have some code that navigates to `MainPage`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check if there is any navigation, but had there been a navigation won't the bug arrive every single time? It only arrives some-times(like once in 6-7 times I start my app). Secondly I have checked matchFullDetails is not set to null anywhere except for in the starting it is left uninitialized, in which case it is null. Inside MainPage constructor, the first line is to instantiate matchFullDetails to point to an object of ObservableCollection.

Comment: Btw my code for catching exception looks like this:-

        if(matchDetails==null){
        int x=10;   // Non-relevant code, THIS LINE IS MARKED AS BREAKPOINT.
        }

Isn't it same as adding Debugger.Break() ??

Comment: It is similar, yes. What is on the call stack then when you get that condition satisfied?

Comment: Hello. Thanks for help. Call stack gave me a fair idea of whats wrong. I have updated the question. Now I know the problem, but how do I solve it? I tried adding
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Mainpage));
but it didn't helped because NullReferenceException is thrown again, because Mainpage is not created yet( I think so).

Comment: I have wasted hours on this. Now I think its not even a bug. It may just be a problem with VS. @Filip Sir Please let me know what do you think. Our timings of appearing on stackoverflow aren't matching hence its taking even longer. Everytime I check you're "seen here" an hour or two ago :-(

Comment: I think this should answer your current question. If you have further questions related to serialization - go ahead and ask, but I think there should be plenty of information on msdn on these topics.

Comment: Here's one article to start on that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh994640.aspx

Sorry about the timing - I only go on Stack Overflow when I have a moment and it's sometimes once a day.

Comment: Thanks your Edit2 should be very helpful. Still I think problem is only limited to me as a debugger. It only occurs when app is suspended from Details page and App is started from VS. It tries to create Details page before Mainpage which causes problems. btw Thanks for the help. Idea of tracking stack call was most helpful.